# SimplePager strange row count

Tags: java, gwt, widget, uibinder

I'm encountering a problem with SimplePager; the problem is that when I clic to display the next page of rows the indicator of rows number multiply by two (for example initially I have to display 30 rows, initially the pager displays " 1-8 of 30 "  However, when I clic to display the next page the indicator displays " 9-16 of 60 ")

By the way to display the pager I defined it on UiBinder file and I did this :

```
simplePager.setDisplay(cellList);
    verticalPanel.add(simplePager);
    verticalPanel.add(cellList);
```

Any help are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're probally adding the same elements to the list you're trying to page.

Check the data loading into the grid or table you're trying to page.

Comment: what do you mean by the data loading ?? I'm loading a cellList of an AsyncDataProvider...

Comment: Precisely, check when you perform such task. Because it seems to me that when you're paging the list the data is being loading again and again. Check if you page two times the data is loaded three times.

Comment: thanks a lot it was a wrong placement of RPC call which I did it in onRangeChanged() 

Problem resolved ...